# Why am I facing empty content problem in gh pages - create-react-app?

Tags: deployment, github-pages

I'm facing problem with github deployment. I have already deployed my react app (create-react-app) and i can access my app but there is no content shown(blank page)

This is my app link:

https://freedomfighterr.github.io/react-organic-shop/

I tried to find problem on stack and chatgpt but I wasn't successful